Efficient way to get all substrings from a given string with wildcards?
Imagine you have a string "b?gb?rd" and a list of strings ["big", "gg", "bird", "dra"], how can you efficiently get all the substrings that matches in the list? The symbol ? means any single character.
Example:
s = "b?gb?rd"
l = ["big", "gg", "bird", "dra"]

Output: ["big", "bird", "gg"]
I've tried a naive approach which probably takes O(n^2) time so I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this.

"I've tried a naive approach" - you forgot to post your initial attempt :)

Just to elaborate on that, not showing your attempt makes this look like you're too lazy to do your homework, which is really frowned upon here. We're willing to help, but not do it completely for you. That said, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

I don't see why "gg" does not match the "?g" in s.

I scrapped my original approach and tried integrating the aho-corasick algorithm to solve my problem. And yes, you're right about "gg" being a match. I'll edit that.

If you had a problem implementing the aho-corasick algorithm, then focus your question on that with all the details of your work and where you got stuck.

"O(n^2)" - What is n?
